# How to manage python project that depends on multiple versions of a shared library?

Tags: python, pip, openssl, homebrew, bokeh

I am on macOS, using `brew`, `pyenv`, and `virtualenv`.

I have a Python project that depends on `bokeh` and `gdal` (both python packages were installed with pip inside a virtual environment). Both bokeh and gdal depend on a system version of `libopenssl`, but they depend on different versions (1.0 and 1.1).

I have had this project working at various points in the past, with some combination of libraries (using pip for all python packages and brew for system packages) but when I change python versions and environments (using pyenv) to work on other projects, and then come back to this project, it no longer works. Usually something along these lines with a problem finding a shared library for openssl:

```
$ ./my_python_program.py
...
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/userBob/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/userBob/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

I feel like I am eventually able to get things to work by trying random combinations of installing and uninstalling various package versions using pip and brew. But this is a fragile and inefficient way to maintain my projects.

In general what is the best way to handle this kind of situation? Do I need to simply record the exact brew and pip install/uninstall commands to get it working? Am I missing the concept of version "pinning"? Are there additional options with brew and pyenv that I am missing that might make this process easier?

Comment: I'm confused, Bokeh does not depend on openSSL.

Comment: Whoops maybe I messed that up with a different library, or bokeh depends on something that depends on openssl?

Comment: Bokeh's dependency list is pretty short. The only thing that might come to mind is Tornado. Perhaps try updating changing your installed version of Tornado?

Comment: Yup now that you mention it, it was tornado. I guess I am after a more general answer about a some kind of pattern or strategy that I am missing re: managing dependencies. Every time I switch projects, I enter a loop of unknown length of installing various versions of different packages, and I think I must be missing a better way to track/manage the situation.

Comment: Have you considered replacing brew, pyenv, and virtualenv with Anaconda (and conda environments?) https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: I have tried conda in the past but it led to similar issues. Re: bokeh/openssl dependency above, yes the problem is with tornado which only comes up when I run `bokeh serve`. Tornado (and actually pip too) want `openssl@1.1`, but my gdal install wants `openssl@1.0`. Homebrew lets me have the files exist for both versions of openssl in `/usr/local`, so how can I get different python modules to refer to the different openssl version that might not be in my path? Or is it a path ordering issue?

Comment: If you need things in the same Python process, then I don't really have any suggestions for a conflicting shared library requirements, except to find or build sets of packages that have compatible requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but I can tell you what I do usually.

- First of all, I'm using Anaconda.
- When I'm on a project, I switch to the relevant virtual environment.
- Before switching out, when I commit/push my modifications, I also create an export file of my environment [like you can find it there](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file).
- I also track this file with git, this way, if I make any modification when working on the environment, it's stored in the .yml file.

This way, I can reinstall all dependencies needed for the project if I format my machine or get a new one, etc. And the reference for every dependency I need is stored in the cloud with my sources. So in case I start getting weird behaviour, I just restore my environment with this reference file from the time when it was working.

I'm not switching between projects fast enough for me to justify automatizing this process, but I'm sure that's feasible if you want to.